# Importing Calendars/Contacts from PST - Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I've been trying to write some VBA to automate an IMAP move from one provider to another. I've got an export of the contacts and calendars from the current mailbox into a PST. What I'm trying to do is import those into the new Outlook Profile, contacts and calendars. However, with the code I've been trying to work with, I get either an "Object doesn't support this function" or it errors out on the "stepping" through part. I was able to get the code to write the contacts/calendars to an imported folder, but not to the actual profile folder. I don't feel like the For Each step at the end is appropriate to step through the contacts but trying to do a Count for the objects, doesn't seem to do it either.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

' Get the main Inbox folder
Const OLInbox = 6    'Inbox Items folder
Const olFolderContacts = 10 'Contacts
Set objOutlook = CreateObject( "Outlook.Application" )
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace( "MAPI" )
Set objInbox = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder( OLInbox ) 'sets objFolder to the Inbox for it's reference
Set objcontactDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
Set objcalendarDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 

' Create the Imported folder in the main inbox
On Error Resume Next
Set objDestFolder = objInbox.Folders("Imported")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set objNewFolder = objInbox.Folders.Add("Imported")
Set objDestFolder = objInbox.Folders("Imported")
End If
On Error Goto 0


' Run the sub
sbImportPST ("C:\temp\Outlook Export.pst")


Sub sbImportPST (strPSTLocalPath)
' Add the PST to Outlook
objNamespace.AddStore (strPSTLocalPath)

' Select the new store
Set objPST = objNamespace.Folders.GetLast
' Rename the Store To be easier To use
objPST.Name = "PSTImport"

objNamespace.RemoveStore objPST
objNamespace.AddStore (strPSTLocalPath)


Set objPSTInbox = objOutlook.Session.Folders("PSTImport1")
Set objPSTInboxItems = objPSTInbox.Items
PSTInboxItemsCount = objPSTInboxItems.count
' Step through all items just discovered and move to Imported Folder
For i = PSTInboxItemsCount To 1 Step -1
    objPSTInboxItems(i).Move objInbox
Next 

Set oFolders = objPSTInbox.Folders("Contacts") 
For Each objContact In oFolders 
    oFolders.Item.MoveTo objcontactDestFolder
Next 

Set oFolders = objPSTInbox.Folders("Calendar") 
For Each objAppointment In oFolders 
    oFolders.Item.MoveTo objcontactDestFolder
Next 
' Remove the PST file from Outlook
objNamespace.RemoveStore objPST
End Sub
```